# Chrome Extension to modify innerHTML of Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, twitter

I am trying to make a chrome extension that changes the names of my twitter users as they appear on my feed. When I try in the google chrome console to do:

$("#fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id").html("Hello!");

The result is just an empty array "[]".

Also when I type:

document.getElementById("#fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id").html("Hello!");

I get the error: "Cannot set property of "html" of null".

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: An empty array (`[]`) means that no HTML elements were found matching your selector. Are you sure you want to use the id selector (`#`)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Basically what I want to do is be able to get the variable that stores the person's name as it shows up on the feed and change it to something else. Do I have to index to a specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use something like this:

```
var twitterNames = $(".fullname.js-action-profile-name.show-popup-with-id");
```

Or something like this:

```
var twitterNames = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id");
```

Once you have the array of all the elements on the page you can index into the array to change them.